# Past participle

Tags: past-tense, participles

Why in this sentence past participle goes without auxiliary verb?

> The table **painted** red, the sofa **covered** with American leather of a reddish colour with little green flowers on it, and the clothes **taken off** in haste overnight

Comment: It's not a sentence. It's a noun phrase. The clause *painted red* modifies *table*, and so on. There's no verb in that sentence fragment you quote because you have not given us the full sentence.

Comment: ["… *the table painted red, the sofa covered with  American leather of a reddish colour with little green flowers on it* … ***looked at him familiarly.*** "](https://books.google.it/books?id=rGNODwAAQBAJ&pg=PT5789&lpg=PT5789&dq=%22The+table+painted+red%22+%22looked+at+him%22&source=bl&ots=N89oVY0rAu&sig=ACfU3U2ynmCrVFAO2C36Kf8p5TMbMikHiA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNnc20q6jiAhUBZ1AKHRc4B1UQ6AEwAnoECA8QAQ#v=onepage&q=%22The%20table%20painted%20red%22%20%22looked%20at%20him%22&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

Your examples are reduced relative clause constructions. "the table painted red" is from "the table which is/was painted red" by deleting the "which is" part.  The deletion transformation has been called "WHIZ".

In turn, for this example, the "is/was" is part of a passive construction, the active form for which would be "someone paints/painted the table red".  Whether the interpretation is present or past tense depends on the context the construction occurs in.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the description before the subject. "The painted red table *was there*", "taken off in haste clothes *were lying on the floor*". The point of the sentence is not description, it's something else or just the subject. And the participle is just additional information we happen to put after it. I don't really know the words that could explain it in terms of grammar but hope it helps.